# Is it safe to remove the c++ volatile here?

Tags: c++, c++11, volatile

Is it safe to remove `volatile` from the definition of `m_flag` here? 
If `m_flag` is not volatile, what would stop compilers from optimizing away this loop's condition: `while (!m_flag) m_cv.wait(lock);` ?
Does the standard (post-C++11) specify explictly that such optimizations are prohibited in such cases?

```
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class foofoo
{
    volatile bool m_flag;
    mutex m_mutex;
    condition_variable m_cv;

public:
    void DoWork()
    {
        m_flag = false;
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(m_mutex);
        auto junk = async(std::launch::async, [this]()
        {
            {
                unique_lock<mutex> lock(m_mutex);
                m_flag = true;
            }
            m_cv.notify_one();
        });
        while (!m_flag) m_cv.wait(lock);
        cout << "ququ" << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    foofoo f;
    f.DoWork();
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In general, `volatile` and multithreading are orthogonal in C++11. Using `volatile` neither adds nor removes data races.

In this case, `m_flag = true;` is *sequenced before* the release of the mutex in the thread launched by `async` ([intro.execution]/p14), which in turn *synchronizes with* the subsequent acquire of the mutex in `m_cv.wait(lock)` ([thread.mutex.requirements.mutex]/p11,25), which in turn is *sequenced before* a subsequent read of `m_flag`. `m_flag = true;` therefore *inter-thread happens before*, and hence *happens before*, the subsequent read. ([intro.multithread]/p13-14)

Since there are no other side effects on `m_flag`, `m_flag = true;` is the *visible side effect* with respect to that read ([intro.multithread]/p15), and that read must therefore read what was stored by the visible side effect, i.e., `true`.

A compiler that "optimizes" away that condition, regardless of whether `volatile` is used, would be non-conforming.

Comment: Thanks! So, in other words, if the body of the loop doesn't change the loop condition, but contains a synchronization "point", to optimize it away a compiler would have to analyze whether the loop condition might be affected by a "visible side effect" from another thread that can synchronize with the same "point"? In practice, compilers would probably just give up and never attempt to optimize such loops away?..

Comment: I mean "optimize away the loop's condition". I've just realized I was saying "loop" everywhere, though obviously the loop would remain, just turn into an infinite loop...

Comment: @MaxGalkin As long as you don't write a data race, the compiler must ensure that changes made by a thread that previously released a mutex is visible to a thread that subsequently acquires the same mutex. I'm not sure if I'd say "never attempt to", but as long as the code is free of data races, there shouldn't be any surprises with a conforming compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You have a call to `wait` inside the loop so there is no way for the compiler to eliminate it. Besides the fact that `wait` might be more-or-less opaque thing to the compiler it contains mutex lock/unlock inside it which effectively prevents compiler of any elimination. So `volatile` is totally useless there.

Comment: I think if you'd use a local boolean variable in that method instead of m_flag, the compiler would be free to optimize the loop's condition away, because the local variable isn't visible to other threads...  regardles of the "wait" inside the loop's body...

Comment: If you used local then probably it would - I'm not a compiler expert. The only way for the compiler to eliminate anything(as I understand it) is to prove that the variable can't be changed in any other place. Any call to the opaque function might hinder this ability tremendously and a compiler would just give up trying. Still if you used the local variable there certainly would be no chance it would be set in any other place if you didn't passed its address anywhere.

Comment: Then this statement from your answer is incorrect: "You have a call to `wait` inside the loop so there is no way for the compiler to eliminate it.". Just having a call to `wait` is not enough to prevent elimination...

Comment: @Max Galkin, my comment is about loop elimination - it can't be eliminated in the OP. But if you have `bool flag = false;` which is used on the `while(flag)` then, in my opinion, compiler might decide that it is a dead end and never execute it since the condition is always false. But it certainly different from your question. You don't have a local variable in the question.